# Reverse for 'topping' not found. 'topping' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

When i try to run server i get the error "Reverse for 'topping' not found. 'topping' is not a valid view function or pattern name." Error at line 11

```
9       <a href="{% url 'pizza:index' %}"> Pizzeria</a>-
10      <a href="{% url 'pizza:pizzas' %}"> Pizzas </a>-
11      <a href="{% url 'pizza:topping' %}"> Toppings </a>
```

views.py

```
  def topping(request, pizza_id):
    pizza = Pizza.objects.get(id=pizza_id)
    toppings = Pizza.topping_set.order_by('id')
    context = {'pizza': pizza, 'toppings' : toppings}
    return render(request, 'pizza/topping.html', context)
```

app/urls.py

```
 urlpatterns = [
    #homepage
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    #pizzas page
    url(r'^pizzas/$', views.pizzas, name='pizzas'),
    # Detail page for a single pizza
    url(r'^topping/(?P<pizza_id>\d+)/$', views.topping, name='topping'),
    ]
```

topping.html

```
  {%block content%}
<p>Pizza : {{pizza}}</p>
<p>Toppings:</p>
<ul>
 {%for topping in toppings%}
  <li>{{topping}}</li>
    {%empty%}
    <li>no topping have been added yet.</li>
 {%endfor%}
```

base.html

```
  <a href="{% url 'pizza:index' %}"> Pizzeria</a>-
    <a href="{% url 'pizza:pizzas' %}"> Pizzas </a>-
    <a href="{% url 'pizza:topping' %}"> Toppings </a>
```

Comment: I don't see any url name with the name **topping** in your url conf.

Comment: it missed to give it..but it doesn't work with that either  url(r'^topping/(?P<pizza_id>\d+)/$', views.topping, name='pizza'),

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any url name with the name **topping** in your url conf.

I think instead of

```
url(r'^pizza/(?P<pizza_id>\d+)/$', views.topping, name='pizza'),
```

It should be

```
url(r'^topping/(?P<pizza_id>\d+)/$', views.topping, name='topping')
```

UPDATE:

The pattern linked to your view has `(?P<pizza_id>\d+)` as parameter,so you should call it by specifying the `pizza_id`.

```
<a href="{% url 'pizza:topping' id %}"> Toppings </a>
```

Where `id` is the `pizza_id` in your template

Comment: Did you change the name like this: `name='topping'`?

Comment: Yes i edited the code in urls. But error remains the same.i am obviously missing something

Comment: I updated my answer, basically your url does not have the id specified